# Transformer in parallel

Tags: transformer

Can I connect transformer secondaries with different voltage in paralel?
       [image]

Comment: No. The difference in turns will appear as shorted.

Comment: What would you expect to happen? If you're trying to add the voltages, you need to connect in series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I ...

We have no way of knowing your capabilities, so there is no way to answer this question.

Connecting multiple transformer secondaries can yield useful results in some cases.  In series, the voltages add, and the current capability is that of the lowest current winding.  In parallel, the voltages must be the same, and the current capability is that of all windings combined.

The above assumes that phase was properly considered.  When polarity of one winding is important relative to other windinds, the schematic shows a dot by one end of each winding.  All the dot ends will be in phase, and 180° out of phase with the not-dot ends.

To usefully parallel two secondaries, both these conditions must be met:

The two windings have the same open circuit output voltage.

The two dot ends are connected, and the two not-dot ends are connected.

When you do this right, you get the combined current capability of both windings, and the voltage of each winding.

Connecting two windings of different voltage is a bad idea.  This effectively shorts part of the transformer against itself.

Comment: 3rd condition exists: Think if the coupling from the primary to one secondary is tight, but loose to the other secondary. It's also a short circuit. This can probably be stated more exactly with some common transformer specs. Maybe you add it, so I can remove this.

Comment: @user287001 the only time the prinary and secondary windings are connected is in an auto-transformer - is that the case here as per the diagram?

Comment: @SolarMike I wrote about coupling, it's magnetic here. It has several characteristics such as mutual inductance . Loose coupling is characterized as big leakage inductance. Galvanic contact is a different thing and I wrote nothing about it.